# Under what circumstances are atomic properties useful?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, properties

Objective-C properties default to `atomic`, which ensures that accessors are atomic but doesn't ensure overall thread-safety (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic)).  My question is, aren't atomic properties redundant in most concurrency scenarios?  For example:

**Scenario 1: mutable properties**

```
@interface ScaryMutableObject : NSObject {}

@property (atomic, readwrite) NSMutableArray *stuff;

@end

void doStuffWith(ScaryMutableObject *obj) {
    [_someLock lock];
    [obj.stuff addObject:something]; //the atomic getter is completely redundant and could hurt performance
    [_someLock unlock];
}

//or, alternatively
void doStuffWith(ScaryMutableObject *obj) {
    NSMutableArray *cachedStuff = obj.stuff; //the atomic getter isn't redundant
    [_someLock lock];
    [cachedStuff addObject:something]; //but is this any more performant than using a nonatomic accessor within the lock?
    [_someLock unlock];   
}
```

**Scenario 2: immutable properties**

I was thinking that maybe atomic properties would be useful for avoiding locks when working with immutable objects, but since immutable objects can point to mutable objects in Objective-C, this isn't really much help:

```
@interface SlightlySaferObject : NSObject {}

@property (atomic, readwrite) NSArray *stuff;

@end

void doStuffWith(SlightlySaferObject *obj) {
    [[obj.stuff objectAtIndex:0] mutateLikeCrazy];//not at all thread-safe without a lock
}
```

The only scenarios I can think of where it's safe to use atomic accessors without a lock (and therefore worth using atomic properties at all) are:

1. Working with properties that are
   primitives;
2. Working with properties that are
   guaranteed to be immutable and not
   to point to mutable objects (such as
   an `NSString` or an `NSArray` of
   immutable objects).

Am I missing something?  Are there any other good reasons to use atomic properties?

Comment: I think the other SO question linked by the post covers it well. atomic only covers *access* to the property -- e.g. you can't get back an int that is half-old and half-new, it'd be all-old or all-new (in the case of obj-c it also makes a guarantee on retain counts). In general, full locks/barriers may be required. However, atomic access (not CAS, which is different) can be used in some "lock-free" algorithms and/or just-get-me-out thread loops. So yes, they cover a limited bit of ground.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C properties: atomic vs nonatomic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic)

Comment: @pst Totally correct and there are some scalar types on some ABIs that can be partial.   I think it was PPC that would put half of a particular scalar type in a register and the other half on the stack such that you could actually get half-new-half-old behavior on an otherwise single-value scalar!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't missing anything;  `atomic`'s usefulness is largely limited only to situations where you need to access or set a particular value from multiple threads *where that value is also integral*.

Beyond a single value, `atomic` cannot be used for thread safety purposes.

I wrote quite a bit about it in a [weblog post a while ago](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2008/01/13/objectivce-c-atomic-properties-threading-andor-custom-settergetter/).

This question is also a [very well posed] duplicate of [What's the difference between the atomic and nonatomic attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic)

Comment: Sorry to restart a thread 3 years later but @bbum, did you mean "where the value isn't integral" since atomicity doesn't guarantee you which value, just a legitimate value? I'm trying to understand this stuff so just asking for my clarification.

Comment: @MoMo Right.  Atomicity just guarantees integrity of the value, not whether you'll get the new or old value.  And even the phrase "beyond a single value" is sometimes incorrect.  On PPC, 64 bit values could sometimes be split between a 32 bit register and a 32 bit stack entry.